# DB2 9.7 Synchronizing two schemas from different databases

Tags: synchronization, db2, backup

I would need to copy all data from database DB1 tablespace TS1 schema S1, to database DB2 tablespace TS2 schema S2. What are my options? I could try to do an ONLINE backup from DB1, but I am unsure if it is easy/possible to restore it to DB2 S2...

Comment: You cannot backup individual schemas. Consider using the `db2move` utility.

Comment: You can skip restoring tablespaces when restoring a backup. As mustaccio already mentioned, you can't take a partial backup. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/shashimannepalli/entry/skipping_tablespaces_while_doing_restore3?lang=en

Comment: @mustaccio DB2 9.7 does have transportable tablespaces that allow you to transport a schema from one database to another.  However in this case if the OP wants to use a different schema in the second database it will not work.

Comment: Tablespaces != schemas. If you happen to have a schema where all objects sit in an isolated set of tablespaces, then it's possible. If not, not. And, as you've mentioned, the schema name changes in the target, so that's not an option anyway.

Comment: Hmm strange, I was able to change logging strategy to archiving from circular, create a backup, restore the backup to a new database, but apparently some problems with rollforwarding: "SQL1276N  Database "[DB]" cannot be brought out of rollforward pending 
state until roll-forward has passed a point in time greater than or equal to 
"2013-11-28-10.10.00.000000 UTC", because node "0" contains information later 
than the specified time.
" Both databases are on the same machien and DB instance, so there should not be clock differences.